# How detect which UICollectionView scrolled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a multiple collectionView in one controller. One of them on top and the second on bottom.  So my question is how to detect which collectionView view is scrolled?(In Objective-c) To detect scrolling i use the method: - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView . But in this method i can’t detect which collectionView is scrolled. Please help with your advice.

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift** You can Check Like This :

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        if scrollView == topCollectionViewName {
            print("Call Top CollectionView")
        }else if scrollView == bottomCollectionViewName{
            print("Call Bottom CollectionView")
        }else{
            print("call any other")
        }
        
}
```

In **Objective C** You can Check Like This :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (scrollView == topCollectionViewName) {
         NSLog(@"Call Top CollectionView");
    }else if (scrollView == bottomCollectionViewName) {
         NSLog(@"Call Bottom CollectionView");
    }else{
            NSLog(@"Call any other");
    }
}
```

Happy To Help You :)

Comment: @TolibovUmid Happy to help You. if this answer right as per your question then please mark as a right answer so it's may be helpfull for another person in feature.

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionView is subclass of UIScrollView so you can compare it

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == collectionViewOne) {

    }else if (scrollView == collectionViewTwo) {

    }else{
            //something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create outlets of your collectionView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var topCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

In scrollView Delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == topCollectionView) {

    }
    else if (scrollView == bottomCollectionView) {

    }
}
```

This will work as UICollectionView is subclass of UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

```
//        create outlets of both collectionview
        @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewA: UICollectionView!
        @IBOutlet weak var collectionVieB: UICollectionView!
        
//        add delegate method to detect scroll of collectionview
//         for swift
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            
            if collectionView == collectionViewA{
                // collectionviewA was scrolled
            }else{
                // collectionviewB was scrolled
            }
            
        }
        
//        same deleagte for objc
        
        - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            // compare both collectionview here like upper swift method
        }
```